# WCF service throws exception when streaming files over 100mb or so

Tags: exception, wcf, streaming

We have a streaming client/server system which runs fine in many sites, and has done so for years
One site is having a problem when streaming files over 100mb or so
Other sites routinely stream files of several hundred mb

Trying to identify the issue we hooked up wcf tracing at the server.
When the transfer fails exceptions are thrown during the reading of the incoming stream. The trace file contains these exceptions (clipped for brevity)

First exception;

````
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, 
System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,             
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Incorrect function</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.ListenerHttpContext.ListenerContextHttpInput.ListenerContextInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.TryEnsureBytes(Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetBuffer(Int32 count, Int32&amp; offset, Int32&amp; offsetMax)
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadText(Boolean hasLeadingByteOf0xEF)
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()```

Second exception;
```<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
at AdeptFileSystemCore.RequestHandlers.RHUpload.Handle(RequestPacket req)```

Third exception;
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.ByteBuffer.FlushAsync()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.DequeueAndFlush(ByteBuffer currentBuffer, AsyncEventArgsCallback callback)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.FlushPendingBuffer()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.Flush()
at System.Xml.XmlStreamNodeWriter.Flush()
at System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter.Flush()
````

Comment: Do you mean that other websites have been working fine with this system for many years, but one website has this problem? I think you can see if the type of file supports being transferred. At the same time, you mentioned that other websites can transfer hundreds of MB of files, but this one can't. Therefore, it should not be a restriction on the transmission of data, but also a limitation on the website itself.